# Microphone isn't working (Kubuntu 17.04)

Tags: kubuntu, 17.04, microphone, pavucontrol

**Hello! I have a lot of troubles with microphone - it doesn't work on my laptop ASUS x556U**
I tried testing in several sites

What shall i do? OR How to solve (from what i should start searching)
Thx in advance

Here's my hardware:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards                                                                                                                               
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf328000 irq 16
$ lspci | grep -i audio                                                                                                                                
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
```

in "alsamixer" it's present and active
[alsamixer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXSZk.png)

Comment: **Is** it **work**ing **now**?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you, guys! Muchisimo gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot indicates that your microphone is muted, displayed with **MM** under the level of **Mic**. Move to highlight your microphone in alsa mixer, and press on **m** key to unmute.

Comment: Thank You oliverb2 !!!!!! It works now. I didn't know that S/PDIF is microphone. Wow!

Comment: Don't forget to update this question as solved ;-)